# Changing UITextView's font size leaks memory

Tags: memory-leaks, uitextview, memory-management, font-size, uifont

I have a slider used to change the font size of the text in a UITextView. Analyzer and Leaks report no memory leak. However, the memory grows each time I change the font size by moving the slider. Eventually the app gets an out of memory warning. The code is:

```
mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:mainSlider.value];
```

If I replace that code with `mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0];`, memory stays the same no matter how many times I move the slider. I searched this and many other sites looking for info on a possible UIFont bug. No success. I see people using the same code I am using and not mentioning increasing memory. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a font cache in place to avoid regenerating the same fonts over and over again (a bit like [UIImage imageNamed:@""])

It is not explicitly stated in the docs but reading

> You do not create UIFont objects using
>   the alloc and init methods. Instead,
>   you use class methods of UIFont to
>   look up and retrieve the desired font
>   object. These methods check for an
>   existing font object with the
>   specified characteristics and return
>   it if it exists. Otherwise, they
>   create a new font object based on the
>   desired font characteristics.

could make one believe there is a cache

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Also, what are you calling an "out of memory warning"? I presume it's just a "memory warning level=1", and not an application crash because of out-of-memory?

Comment: Thank you very much. The caching would certainly explain it. You are correct in that I am not experiencing an application crash, just a warning. Here is another piece of evidence that supports your theory:

Comment: Here is my code now:   `if (mainSlider.value < [UIFont systemFontSize]) {
   mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
  } else if (mainSlider.value < 25) {
   mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
  } else if (mainSlider.value < 50) {
   mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
  } else if (mainSlider.value < 75) {
   mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:75];
  } else if (mainSlider.value < 100) {
   mainText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100];
  } `

Comment: This code works because I assign only a limited set of font objects as the slider is moved. Previously, many, many font objects would be cached since the slider value moves in float increments (i.e. 0.01). I think that this is the reason for the excessive memory usage. It is NOT a leak, but it is using up resources just the same.